# Download popup still appearing in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

My problem is that the download popup window is displaying, while i want download file by chrome, using selenium and java. BUT. On other PC this problem doesn't occur - files are downloading to path i get in code.

My question is: what can be a problem with one PC. The version of chrome and chromedriver are the same on both PC's.

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
    chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this preference

```
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePrefs.put("directory_upgrade", true);
```

Comment: added, still the same problem

Comment: What type of file you are trying to download? It seems like the directory you are trying to use as download_directory doesn't have the right permissions to save a file.

Comment: Its simple txt files, i have permission because i can save the file in given directory while using popup.

Answer (score 0):

Add this preference to see if this works.

`chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);`

Comment: But its not pdf file

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem.
There was two scenarios, for two different pages:

1. On 1st I just click on button to download, this code working pretty good:

   ```
   HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
   chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
   chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
   chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false"); // to disable security check eg. Keep or cancel button
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
   options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
   options.addArguments("test-type");
   options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
   DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
   cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
   ```
2. On second, i trigger JS functions, which was responsible for triggering download file:

   ```
       HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
   chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
   chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
   chromePrefs.put("directory_upgrade", true);
   chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false"); // to disable security check eg. Keep or cancel button
   chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1);
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
   options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
   options.addArguments("test-type");
   options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
   options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
   DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
   cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
   ```