Selenium chrome-standalone download file without popup
I'm trying to run Selenium in docker. Therefore I have the selenium/standalone-chrome together with node in my docker-compose:
# Inspired by https://www.testmo.com/guides/github-actions-selenium/
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    shm_size: '2gb'
    ports:
      - 4444:4444 # Selenium service
      - 5900:5900 # VNC server
      - 7900:7900 # VNC browser client
    volumes:
      - ./:/project
      - ./download:/Downloads
    working_dir: /project

  node:
    image: node:19
    volumes:
      - ./:/project
    working_dir: /project
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - chrome

I use Selenium with JavaScript. In my test file in my before I try to convince chrome not to open a popup for download, since I can't easily interact with that:
before(async () => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(downloadDirectory)){
        fs.mkdirSync(downloadDirectory);
    }
    const downloadPath = path.resolve('download');
    let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.setUserPreferences({
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
        "download.default_directory": downloadPath,
        "download.prompt_for_download": false,
        "download.directory_upgrade": true,
        "download.prompt_for_download": false,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": true,
        "plugins.plugins_disabled": "Chrome PDF Viewer",
        "pdfjs.disabled": true,
        "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"
    });

    const host = process.env.SELENIUM || undefined;
    const server = host ? `http://${host}:4444` : '';
    driver = await new Builder()
        .usingServer(server)
        .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build()
    await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: implicitWait });
});

However, when I run the test inside docker (I'm getting inside with docker compose exec node bash and run the tests with SELENIUM=chrome npx mocha test/badge.spec.js), I still get a popup. What am I doing wrong? If you want to see the whole code, you can see it here.

seems like you should use downloadDirectory, but be sure to wait for creation of the dir.

The download directory is configured by download.default_directory, isn't it? And I am already waiting for the creation of the directory

wasn't sure why the path.resolve is there...

@browsermator to get the full path. I don't think that's the proplem, since it works fine outside of docker.

double-check that path... not too sure about the async anonymous function and if you're waiting there.  You shouldn't need path.resolve... just use an absolute path to begin with.

path.resolve is a node function, so it's not async. Or did you mean something else? Also I can't use an absolute path since I'm both running on a local machine directly and in docker - besides, an absolute path is just less flexible and has no advantages here.

not familiar with running Selenium in node, so the async() anonymous function looks weird to me (it's probably fine).  The path you send to the browser, though will need to be absolute.  Relative in your code will be relative to where that code is running.  The browser has no idea where the code is running from and would (I think) require an absolute path... if it were relative it would be relative to where the browser is running which would be different than your relative path in code.  Assuming downloadPath is correct, you should also check permissions there.  Browser will fallback on bad.

Try to disable security check like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61498317/3730077
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
...
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");


This doesn't solve the problem. The popup still pops up.

Or maybe it does, but I don't know how to set this option. The example you provided is for Java, but I'm using JavaScript. I couldn't find an option to set chromePrefs / experimental options there. I tried setting it in the normal options, but that didn't work.

something like this:     `const chromePrefs = {
'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
'download.default_directory': 'path/to/download/directory',
'download.prompt_for_download': false,
'safebrowsing.enabled': false
};
const options = new chrome.Options();
options.setUserPreferences(chromePrefs);`


that is exactly what I tried but it doesn't solve the problem. The popup still pops up.
